# comparing two numbers, getting the different bits in them and filling up a 16bit register, objective-C

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, bit-manipulation

this may be a bit confusing. I have two numbers, say
x = 56 = 00111000
y = 50 = 00110010
we can see that there a total of 4 different bits between them. we need to take those bits and fill up part of the 8 bit register. and in the same way take another two numbers ( say there are another 4 bits different in them ) then fill up the remaining part of the 8 bit register. 
Does anyone know how to do this using objective-c ?

Comment: What does "fill up part of the 8bit register" mean? What does "fill up the remaining part of the 8 bit register" mean? Give examples, or better yet, tell us why you are doing it.

Comment: So in your example you want to take `01` in bit-2 (assuming you start bit indexing from 1) and `10` bit-4 and push it into a register as `0110` or `1001`. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: this 56 and 50 are the outputs of shake events performed in two itouches. so lets take an 8bit register. then the we can see that there are 4 bits different. so we can place those bits in the 8bit register. and then , after shaking the two itouches again, we get two other numbers. the bits which are different are again placed in the remaining places in the 8bit register. I hope that made some sense

Comment: @yasouser : yes thats rit. pushing them anyone way will be fine

Comment: Tough. The iPhone has 32-bit registers, and some 64-bit ones, and (on armv7) even some 128-bit ones.

Comment: @tc: then if we use a 32bit register. how do we start pushing these different bits into that?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know Objective-C, so wrote it in C and tested it. Hope you don't mind:

```
unsigned int diffbits(unsigned int x, unsigned int y)
{
  unsigned int xor_xy = x^y;
  unsigned int result = 0;
  unsigned int count = 0;

  while (xor_xy)
  {
    if ( xor_xy & 0x01)
    {
      result |= ((x & (1 << count)) >> count);
      result <<= 1;

      result |= ((y & (1 << count)) >> count);
      result <<= 1;
    }

    ++count;
    xor_xy >>= 1;
  }

  // undo the last left shift of 'result' in the while-loop.
  result >>= 1;

  return result;
}
```

The logic is: `x ^ y` (x XOR y) - gives the bit locations in which the numbers `x` and `y` are different. Test `x` with the bit value of `x ^ y` and push it into `result`. Repeat it with `y` and push it into `result`. Now right shift `x ^ y` by `1`. Repeat until `x ^ y != 0`.

Comment: yea thats k. I understood this whole code but I myself am kinda new to objective c. So I donno how to convert this into Objective-C

Comment: From what I know, Objective-C is a strict superset of C. So the `diffbits()` function as such should work in Objective-C as well.

Comment: when am tryin to execute the above code, this is coming up. nested functions are disabled, use -fnested-functions to re-enable. do u know what this is?

Comment: @user531: See this thread for the nested function problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1418707/why-am-i-seeing-the-nested-functions-are-disabled-error

Answer (score -2):

you can get difference using

```
x = 56 = 00111000
y = 50 = 00110010

z = x | y
```

Comment: Don't you mean XOR (^)? OR is hardly the "difference" as I read the OPs question.

Comment: i dont require the xor. I need the bits which are different when both the numbers are compared. then push them into an 8bit register

Comment: @user640599 A bitwise XOR, which stands for exclusive or, means that bits will be set if they are different in the two numbers.